# Cannot access Network Shares on Windows Server 2008 running VisualSVN Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, visualsvn-server

I have installed VisualSVN server on Windows Server 2008. The server is part of a domain but not the domain controller, it is just a data server and now an SVN server. VisualSVN uses port 80 and can only be access from inside the network (i do i by going to the dns name of the server). However, ever since i have installed this, other computers on the network can no longer access the shared folders on the server EXCEPT the domain controller which has no problems accessing the shares.

I am stumped, i am guessing it is something to do with Apache running and not using host-headers (or whatever the Apache equivalent may be) but just being bound to the servers DNS name or IP.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us much to go on, but it seems unlikely that a web service binding to port 80 should stop file sharing from working. This is a fairly typical situation and should work well enough. My guess is that either DNS is somehow messed up, there is a permissions problem or the server is somehow misconfigured. More information is needed; what troubleshooting steps have you tried?

- Any clues in the event log?
- What error message do you get when you try to access the shares?
- If you stop the VisualSVN service, does this restore the shares to working order?

Comment: It seems to have been fixed now. I am not entirely sure what was going on but in VisualSVN the port was bound to all IP's, as soon as i specified a single IP everything seemed to work again. It is weird because this doesn't strike me as either the cause or a solution.